# Checking if first letter of string is in uppercase

Tags: python

I want to create a function that would check if first letter of string is in uppercase. This is what I've came up with so far:

```
def is_lowercase(word):
    if word[0] in range string.ascii_lowercase:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

When I try to run it I get this error:

```
    if word[0] in range string.ascii_lowercase
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone have a look and advise what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `range` is a builtin function that returns a range of numbers, and has no place whatsoever in that code.

Comment: avoid the pattern `if [bool]: return True: else return False`.  you can simply use `return [bool]`

Comment: It's just simply `if word[0] in string.ascii_lowercase`, there is no need for range.

Comment: Or better yet, `return word[0] in string.ascii_lowercase`

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Why not use `str.isupper()`;

```
In [2]: word = 'asdf'   
In [3]: word[0].isupper()
Out[3]: False

In [4]: word = 'Asdf'   
In [5]: word[0].isupper()
Out[5]: True
```

Comment: This is a good answer but I was looking to learn what I did wrong in the code I wrote rather than just look for a different solution to the same problem. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @gameFace Good point. Sometimes the best solution is a different solution. ;)

Comment: @Blücher In that case, I suggest `Code Review`, instead of `Stack Overflow`.

Comment: one way could be is to use split. if you are sure there would be multiple words with space as separator then this might be a solution: `w="Hello world  w.split()[0].istitle()`

Answer (score 36):

This is built-in for strings:

```
word = "Hello"
word.istitle() # True
```

but note that `str.istitle` looks whether **every word** in the string is title-cased, so this might give you a surprise:

```
"Hello world".istitle() # returns False!
```

If you just want to check the very first character of a string use this:

```
word = "Hello world"
word[0].isupper() # True
```

Comment: Visceral reaction: in the original post, before you edited, you didn't make it clear that phrases like "Hello world" and "HELlo" fail.  istitle checks that every word satisfies the format of <uppercase><sequence of lowercase characters>, and it wasn't clear if that was a restriction given by the OP.  Rolled back downvote

Comment: Thank you, I've seen this but wanted to create something myself rather than use istitle().

Comment: @gameFace: Why? If this is for an excersice then I doubt it's usefulness, but if it's for real code than it's downright bad.

Comment: @nightcracker It's for an exercise, I feel I learn more by creating something new (even if it's usefulness is doubtful) rather than by blindly using ready made solutions - at least at the stage I'm right now.

Comment: Never use `istitle()` function. It can lead to strange hard to find bug. For example try it `"Father's".istitle()` and then imagine that you have to debug the wrong behavior without knowing what this is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The syntax error stems from the fact that you need parentheses:

```
range(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

But in fact you shouldn't use range.  It's as simple as:

```
if word[0] in string.ascii_lowercase
```

Comment: Testing if it is in `ascii_lowercase` could lead to localization problems down the road -- better to use isupper().  For example, what if the word is in Cyrillic?  The first character would be upper case, but it would not be in `ascii_lowercase`.

Comment: `string.ascii_lowercase` is not an integer, and isn't a valid argument to `range()`.

Comment: @Wooble explaining why the syntax error arose in the first place.  Hence I wrote "you shouldn't use range" afterwards, to make sure I wasn't advocating using that solution