# How find indices of specific items in a list?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, indexing, enumerate

I want to print the items with the index number in the output but I can't do it. This is how my script works:

1.Takes a string from the user and removes periods and commas.
2. Splits the string into a list called `reshte.`.
3. Delete the First Item from the list at index 0.
4. Scan the list whose first charter is capital then displays it in output.

Input:

> The Persian League is the largest sport event dedicated to the
> deprived areas of Iran. The Persian League promotes peace and
> friendship.  This video was captured by one of our heroes who wishes
> peace.

My code:

```py
bs = [',','.']
reshte = input()
for s in bs:
    if s in reshte:
        reshte = reshte.replace(s,'')

reshte = reshte.split()
b = reshte[0]
css = [reshte.remove(b) for k in reshte if b in reshte]


for f in reshte:
    if f[0] == f[0].upper():
       print(f)
```

Output:

```
Persian
League
Iran
Persian
League
```

Expected output:

```
2:Persian
3:League
15:Iran
17:Persian
18:League
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried!

Comment: I don't think the tags `project` and `z-index` are at all relevant to your post. Please remove them

Comment: One way to achieve this will be to find all indices of elements in list using [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list) , store the result in another dict. and pop first index from dict on each occurrence of element

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the input that's giving you that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Patrick did gave you an answer but then you said that is wrong, I assume that the results of the index is supposed to be index **before** removing the firs element in the list (step 3) and adding 1 to the index, because the results seems the index as we normally count and not as they are counted in Python (or most of Programming languages, see below for Guides).

I also see that in the result there isn't the word 'This' so I assume that you want **ALSO** to skip all words that starts with capital and are the same as the first element of list, so the word 'The'.

### 1. Using a List as result

```py
test_string = """The Persian League is the largest sport event dedicated, \
to the deprived, areas of Iran. The Persian League promotes, peace and friendship.  
This video was captured by one of our heroes, who wishes peace.
"""

bs = [',', '.']
result_2 = []
# ========== < REMOVE COMMAS AND DOTS > ========= #
for punct in bs:
    if punct in test_string:
        test_string = test_string.replace(punct, '')


# ========== < STORE FIRST ELEMENT AT INDEX 0 > ========= #
reshte = test_string.split()
first_element = reshte[0]


# ========== < COUNTS ELEMENTS IN LIST > ========= #
results = []
for idx, f in enumerate(reshte):
    if first_element[0] == f[0]: # NOTE: we don't remove the first element but only skipping it all in once
        continue
    if f[0].isupper():
        results.append((idx, f))

for idx, value in results:
    print(f'{idx+1}:{value}')

# 2:Persian
# 3:League
# 15:Iran
# 17:Persian
# 18:League
```

### 2. Using a Dictionary

```py
results = dict()
for idx, f in enumerate(reshte):
    if first_element[0] == f[0]: # NOTE: we don't remove the first element
        continue
    if f[0].isupper():
        results[idx] = f

for key, value in results.items():
    print(f'{key+1}:{value}')
    
# 2:Persian
# 3:League
# 15:Iran
# 17:Persian
# 18:League

print(results)

# {1: 'Persian', 2: 'League', 14: 'Iran', 16: 'Persian', 17: 'League'}
```

### 3. Count Duplicate of list

```py
# ========== < FIND UNIQUE ELEMENT IN LIST > ========= #
unique_string = {string for string in reshte if string[0].isupper()}
results = []
# ========== < COUNT ELEMENTS  > ========= #
for element in unique_string:
    if first_element[0] == element[0]:
        continue
    element_count = reshte.count(element)
    results.append((element_count, element))

for idx, value in results:
    print(f'{idx}:{value}')
# 1: Iran
# 2: League
# 2: Persian
```

### 4. Use Counter

```py
from collections import Counter

counted = Counter(reshte)

for element, count in counted.items():
    if element[0] == first_element[0]:
        continue
    elif element[0].isupper():
        print(f'{count}:{element}')
        
# 2:Persian
# 2:League
# 1:Iran
```

### Guides & Documentations

- [python_access_list_items](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_access_list_items.asp)
- [geeksforgeeks.org | isupper-islower-lower-upper](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/isupper-islower-lower-upper-python-applications/)
- [Python Docs | collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

### Stack Overflow related questions

- [Checking if first letter of string is in uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353968/checking-if-first-letter-of-string-is-in-uppercase)
- [understanding-slice-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)
- [how-to-access-list-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613131/how-to-access-list-elements)
- [how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Answer (score 0):

Solve this using enumerate and the sep option of print. Just change the last for loop.

```
for i, f in enumerate(reshte):
    if f[0] == f[0].upper():
       print(i, f, sep=":")
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Please be careful and once in my question. See the output I want