# how can i find the words in a string that start with capital letter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I find the words in a string that start with a capital letter?

Example input:

```py
input_str = "The Persian League is the largest sport event dedicated to the deprived areas of Iran. The Persian League promotes peace and friendship. This video was captured by one of our heroes who wishes peace."
```

Expected output:

```
Persian League Iran Persian League
```

Comment: What about `The` and `This`? Is there a stoplist?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. I'm happy you're getting good answers here, but just want to mention, you'll generally get better answers if you put in some effort to finding a solution yourself. To start, there are existing questions about [splitting a string into words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/743806/4518341) and [checking if a word is capitalized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7353968/4518341).

Comment: Is the issue resolved? If so, please mark the correct answer as accepted to close it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you can accept `The` and `This` as well:

```
import re
input_string = "The Persian League is the largest sport event dedicated to the deprived areas of Iran. The Persian League promotes peace and friendship. This video was captured by one of our heroes who wishes peace."
matches = re.findall("([A-Z].+?)\W", input_string)
```

gives

```
['The', 'Persian', 'League', 'Iran', 'The', 'Persian', 'League', 'This']
```

If you need to ignore `The` and `This`:

```
matches = re.findall("(?!The|This)([A-Z].+?)\W", input_string)
```

gives

```
['Persian', 'League', 'Iran', 'Persian', 'League']
```

Comment: You can simplify this by matching word characters positively instead of negatively: `r"[A-Z]\w*"`

Answer (score 2):

Without regex:

```
txt = "The Persian League is the largest sport event dedicated to the deprived areas of Iran. The Persian League promotes peace and friendship."

print([w for w in txt.split() if w.istitle()])
```

Output:

```
['The', 'Persian', 'League', 'Iran.', 'The', 'Persian', 'League']
```

If you want to skip the `The` word (or any other word for that matter) try this:

```
print(" ".join(w.replace(".", "") for w in txt.split() if w[0].isupper() and w not in ["The", "This"]))
```

Output:

```
Persian League Iran Persian League
```

Comment: I mentioned this as a comment on another answer that `istitle` may result in unexpected behavior since it will return `False` if other capitalized letters exist in the string

Comment: Also, using `.split()` will result as `'Iran.'` (with dot).

Comment: Regex certainly seems the better choice if you need to ignore stopwords IMO.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = """
The Persian League is the largest sport event dedicated to the deprived areas 
of Iran. The Persian League promotes peace and friendship. This video was 
captured by one of our heroes who wishes peace.
"""
print( [ x for x in s.split() if x[0].isupper() ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import re
inputString = "The Persian League is the largest sport event dedicated to the deprived areas of Iran. The Persian League promotes peace and friendship."
splitted = re.split(' |\.', inputString)
result = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0 and x[0].isupper(), splitted)
print(list(result))
```

Result:

```
['The', 'Persian', 'League', 'Iran', 'The', 'Persian', 'League']
```

Comment: `filter(lambda)` is ugly. Use a comprehension instead: `[w for w in b if w[0] >= 'A' and w[0] <= 'Z']`

Comment: Even less ugly, use the builtin `istitle` method of `str` objects: `[w for w in b if w.istitle()]`

Comment: @Antimon `istitle` may result in unexpected behavior. It will return `False` if there are other capitalized letters in the string (ie `PerSian`)

Comment: Which is ugly is just your opinion. IMO, I prefer `filter` than comprehension.

Comment: @Wondercricket Good point. `w[0].isupper()` would work better. I just find the looks of the string comparisons a bit confusing.

Comment: @Antimon `isupper()`  method is good. I will update my answer with that method.

Comment: @111e75b0 Fair enough :) You do you, I'm just [opinionated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61945553/4518341) about overusing functional constructs. Python is a multi-paradigmatic language for a reason after all. Sorry if I sounded judgy.

Answer (score -2):

Another way to solve is using `for` to read data and put the words with capital letters in a list.

```
phrase = 'The Persian League is the largest sport event dedicated to the deprived areas of Iran. The Persian League promotes peace and friendship. This video was captured by one of our heroes who wishes peace.'

wordsplit = phrase.split(' ')
capitalLettersWords = []
for word in wordsplit:
    if word[0].isupper():
        capitalLettersWords.append(word)

print(capitalLettersWords)
#['The', 'Persian', 'League', 'Iran.', 'The', 'Persian', 'League', 'This']
```

In my example I used the [str.isupper()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isupper#str.isupper) and [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split), both built-in methods from Python standard lib.

Comment: This is exactly what list comprehensions mean to avoid. No need to bend over backwards to make your code slower *and* more complicated at the same time.

Comment: I would like to write a no-list-comprehension version.